# 'Oops!' error when editing a former edit (which was in the review queue)

Tags: bug

Steps:

1. edited an answer with spelling and grammar issues
2. submitted it, edit is only visible to me until it's reviewed
3. I spotted 2 remaining spelling errors that I oversaw
4. 2nd edit (last not peer-reviewed yet)
5. "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" when I tried to submit

Here's the Oops:
https://android.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/posts/24927/edit-submit/197c7f85-a57d-4d73-a9a9-653c87203962

Comment: Hmm, I've done that lots of times on other sites without issue.  You're unlucky :).  One of the devs should see this soon.

Comment: @Matthew Read: As this is just a bug report I it's marginally useful for normal meta users. I assume it's value degrades over time (and becomes null if the devs fix it). (When) Should I vote to delete?

Comment: It doesn't hurt anything for this to stick around.  If you were able to verify that the issue was fixed or no longer occurs then we could delete it, but in this case I think we need dev confirmation.

Comment: I think it's time to add a 'status-*' tag to this. 'Oops' errors are automatically reported to the dev's and it's likely already fixed.